# "usb 3-2: can't set config #1, error -110" - USB keyboard works in Windows 8 laptop but on PC only until Linux boots

Tags: usb, keyboard, kernel-modules

I tried 2 new USB keyboards that work until Linux starts booting.

When booting I saw:

```
[    8.365211] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a2c, idProduct=0b23
[    8.404863] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    8.444623] usb 3-2: Product: USB Keyboard
[   10.641472] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   13.481363] usb 3-2: can't set config #1, error -110
[   13.523672] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   13.804028] usb 3-2: new low-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
```

`lsusb` shows no keyboard.

*I can't try anything requiring SuperUser permissions because it requires my password.*

> **I've found using google:**

- **110** is related to **power**, some say not enough others it's overcurrent protection
- Toggle `usb legacy mode` in BIOS.I toggled it and also `usb 1.1 emulation` (description mentions typing special keyboard keys) and `plug n play aware os`
- Unload ehci module (responsible for usb 2.0) **requires root** and all usb devices will work slower

(To type, I would keep using Ultimate Control (requires Android) that I have installed earlier but it can't even type normally because it capitalizes letters randomly {it didn't do that before this problem, maybe this is a coincidence} and no android keyboard has all PC keyboard keys working as on a PC keyboard or have them at all.)

> **This occurs with:**

- *Titanum TK101* and *Tracer Patriot Black* keyboard (these keyboards look identical except logo and key stickers, maybe hardware is same)
- K8T NEO-FSR Motherboard version 1.0 with **last BIOS**
- COLORSIT 330U-FPH PSU
- AMD Venice 3000+ CPU
- **Lubuntu 14.04/10 64-bit** OS (I've run `do-release-upgrade -d` and update it everyday)
- Linux 3.16-rc3
- BIOS always showing **CPU stepping as CG** and its temp as less than 30°C and motherboard temp always less than 40°C and voltages within ATX specification. I don't know how:

  1. correct these values are
  2. much they change during work.

> UPDATE this problem is being avoided by using a keyboard which is exactly the same model (tracer patriot black) but with a ps/2 connector.The seller said me these keyboards work on Linux/Ubuntu machines (telling Me he installs Linux sometimes for his clients), making Me believe the problem is also caused by my old PC machine.

**Any other info? I don't know what else, please tell Me**

Comment: Is it BIOS or UEFI? Many UEFI firmwares will have a *legacy usb mode* selection - I suggest you toggle it and see what you get.

Comment: It's AMI BIOS, latest versionVeRSiOn

Comment: the capitalisation caused by ultimate control wifi android keyboard(I dont like it)

Comment: I think error -110 means insufficient power. Did you plug the keyboard into an unpowered hub?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I unplugged all usb and other unessetial devices and plugged the keyboard in several different usb ports on the motherboard.I don't know if a motherboard usb port is "unpowered"How can I check? (I just searched on google and nothing relevant)

Comment: return it. get one that works.

Comment: I've found on most google answers that 110 is related to power, some say specifically not enough or it's overcurrent protection.The keyboard works fine on laptop though with win 8

Comment: @mikeserv I'm worried that my PC is the problem not the keyboard :/   

But I can't afford new hardware yet :/

Comment: so this is not a new usb keyboard? like, it used to work but now it doesn't? what has changed?

Comment: @mikeserv this is a brand new keyboard, bought it yesterday

Comment: so return it - get one that works!

Comment: @mikeserv I toggled the usb legacy mode and even 1.1 emulation (the help description mentions keyboards) several times trying on different motherboard usb ports

Comment: @mikeserv I'd like to but it's not possible,what else can I do??

Comment: @illuminÉ thanks I've just edited title because of you :)

Comment: There is a keyboard from the same brand Airen, but with a different device id that [have quirk HID_QUIRK_NOGET](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/hid/usbhid/hid-quirks.c). [And a message saying this keyboard had a lot of bugs](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg59091.html). Maybe it's also the case for the model you have.

Comment: @Leiaz I don't understand why did you write "same brand Airen" The keyboard is Titanum TK101.Also what is this quirk thingy?

Comment: @illuminÉ Actually it cost me 5.75 eur.This is only a temporary solution before I buy the best keyboard.(I need keyboard now but don't want to spend too much on a keyboard Ima use only 4 a short time, and I can't buy that best keyboard yet)

Comment: I understand the situation... unfortunately I don't know how to solve the issue. You have a recent kernel/distribution, and it's a plain keyboard. It works with MS. Just weird.

Comment: @illuminÉ This problem is avoided with buying a ps/2 kayboard instead.This doesn't solve the 110 error though.Because of my visits to nearest PC shop trying different usb keyboards (totalling about 5 hours) I've been told by the seller that these keyboards work on Linux machines with Ubuntu, making me believe that the problem is also caused by my old computer.

Comment: Your board has the same components as [this](http://kmuto.jp/debian/hcl/MSI/K8T+Neo-V). It's quite old school but it's usb 2.0. Check your manual for maybe something in particular about usb? Also, make sure you have the final bios for that board.

Comment: @illuminÉ Bios is latest version.I don't know why you wrote "Your board has the same components as this" Manual says nothing relevant.

Comment: I put an hyperlink to the Debian HCL - I'm saying there is no reason why Linux couldn't run on this, catering to your idea about this being "caused by [your] old computer".

Comment: The [vendor id 0x1a2c is listed as Airen in the kernel sources](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/hid/hid-ids.h). Cheap keyboards are often sold under different names. Quirks are when a device doesn't work in a completely standard way, I think you can specify them when loading the module.

Comment: Just a little more info:  Removing the Hex Value and using 1a2c for a USB ID yields China Resource Semico Co., Ltd.  Using 0b23 yields Pan-Asia Electronics Co., Ltd.  See [this List of USB ID's](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids)

Comment: `error -110`; this is `ETIMEDOUT`.  You can see the [USB error code](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/usb/error-codes.txt) and the [numbers are different per architecture](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h), but 110 is usually `ETIMEDOUT`.  It may indicate a power issue, but it could be other things as well (long cable, intermittent connector, etc).  You can always try other ports and using a HUB as well as just reconnecting.  All are probably kludgy ways to get things working which avoid underlying issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen to me once when I kept my USB camera plugged into the computer on the same bus. The camera was saturating the bus (even when not in use) and actually sending data right at the limit of that USB bus.

Try unplugging the other USB devices. I noticed this by checking `dmesg`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (code -110) with e-book on OpenSUSE Leap 42.2.
When I connected e-book to computer with Windows 8.1, it said: "Your disk has a problem, let`s check it". I.e. I used standart windows-program "chkdsk" to check the both storages in e-book. Finally, everything is ok on Windows and OpenSUSE